# How to know admob ad clicked or not

Tags: android, firebase, admob

How to know admob ad clicked or not. When someone click on an admob add I want to notice that. I want to change a value when ad will be clicked. Is there any android developer who can solve my problem.  I have been tired finding this solution.  I have searched on YouTube  but can't get anything.   Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

You can look at Google Analytics data on your Google Developer account to get stats about viewed and clicked ads.

Otherwise, you can't react programmatically in your app, because you can't constrain someone to click on ads.

Look at distribution guidelines on android.developer.com !

If you still wish to achieve it, you must listen for click events on the container layout of that ad.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do to check some Ads features, but as you know, you can't verify when the ad is clicked.

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx");
    InterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    InterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxx");
    InterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    InterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            mPoints.setText(new Integer(points).toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            AdFailedToLoad=true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            mName.setTextSize(25);
            mName.setText("User : " + intent_user);
            switchToScreen(R.id.screen_score);
        }
    });
```

I hope that this part of my code will help you :D